# Working in $S_7$ solve the equations $(1234)x=(45)(17)$ and $x^2=(45)(17).$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

> Working in $S_7$ solve the equations $(1234)x=(45)(17)$ and $x^2=(45)(17).$

For the first one I got that $(1234)^{-1}(1234)x=(1234)^{-1}(45)(17) \Longrightarrow x=(4321)(45)(17) =(17432).$ Trying to verify the result I ended up with $$(1234)(17432)=(17)(2)(3)(4)=(17)$$ what might I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(4321)(45)(17) =(174532)\neq (17432)$$